# Codeigniter `include` and `$this->view`

Tags: codeigniter, view, standards

For example, there's main view that include partial view from another view. What is better between:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>
    <?php $this->view("anotherview.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>
    <?php include "anotherview.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the first one is the official way to the in Codeigniter's View. But is there any tradeoff/concern if i use the second version?

Comment: first one is not official way it is $this->load->view("anotherview.php");

Comment: It is actually on the Codeigniter user guide. The first one is used if calling another view inside view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474641/why-should-i-use-an-mvc-framework-for-php

But in short, no you do not have to use `$this->view("anotherview.php");` however, if you do not use it, then there is not much point using the codeigniter framework altogether.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a deeper explanation on MVC Concept on PHP!